# Loop through map on returned XML to get node value

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, c++11, pugixml

In my C++ program I spit out nodes from an XML file. I have a standard schema which may not be followed by the input file. I therefore need to map a node title with the information type which is contained within it.

```
#include "pugi/pugixml.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{

    const std::map<std::string, std::string> tagMap {
        {"description", "content"}, {"url", "web_address"}
    };

    pugi::xml_document doca, docb;
    std::map<std::string, pugi::xml_node> mapa, mapb;

    if (!doca.load_file("a.xml") || !docb.load_file("b.xml")) { 
        std::cout << "Can't find input files";
        return 1;
    }

    for (auto& node: doca.child("data").children("entry")) {
    const char* id = node.child_value("id");
    mapa[id] = node;
    }

    for (auto& node: docb.child("data").children("entry")) {
    const char* idcs = node.child_value("id");
        if (!mapa.erase(idcs)) {
        mapb[idcs] = node;
        }
    }

    // For removed
    for (auto& ea: mapa) {
    std::cout << "Removed:" << std::endl;
    ea.second.print(std::cout);
    }

    // For added
    for (auto& eb: mapb) {
        // Loop through tag map
        for (auto& kv : tagMap) {
            // Try to find the tag name named in second map value
            // and associate it to the type of information in first map value
            std::cout << "Found" << kv.first;
            std::cout << "which has value" << node.child_value(kv.second)
        }
    }

}
```

The information I am particualy asking for help with is within `for (auto& eb: mapb) {`. Here I am trying to look at the XML recevied and see if I can match the tags to names in the map (i.e content and web_address) and if so, print the value of the node, associating it to what is it (i.e description or url).

I haven't been able to test this because of this compilation error, which I don't understand because I have refered to node above:

`g++ -g -Wall -std=c++11 -I include -o main src/main.cpp include/pugi/pugixml.cpp 
src/main.cpp:51:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'node'
                        std::cout << "which has value" << node.child_value(kv.second)`

My expected output is this:

- Found description which has this value Hello!
- Found url which has this value www.hotmail.com

From this input

```
<content>Hello!</content>
<web_address>www.hotmail.com</web_address>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear:  you didn't define `node` in the scope of your output code.

When you defined the node in `for (auto& node: ...)` , it's visible only in the scope of the `for` loop.

It's not totally clear for me what it should be but I guess you should replace `node.child_value(kv.second)` with something like `eb.second.child_value(kv.second)`

Comment: Is it a case that I should be defining node in that loop, or am I instead incorrect by trying to use node when I should be using something else? Should it be kv.child_value for example ?

Comment: @JamesWillson I think you should use something else.  `kv.second.child_value (...)` could be a good candidate.  `eb.second...` another  one (because otherwhse you would loop through mapb without doing anything with its elements...).